# How to get string value from Listbox as user selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I can't get string value from Listbox after selected one item.

In my Listbox I have the Image (blinding source) and TextBlock (blinding source).

My code at .xaml page:

```
        <ListBox Name="carListBox" Height="431" Canvas.Left="28" Canvas.Top="65" Width="446" SelectionChanged="ListBoxOnSelection">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Name="brandImage" Source="{Binding Image}" Width="100" Height="150"></Image>
                        <Image Name="carImage" Source="{Binding Image}" Width="150" Height="150"></Image>
                        <TextBlock Name="textDisplay" Text="{Binding ShowDetail}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

My code at .xaml.cs page (C#)

private void ListBoxOnSelection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)

```
    {
       MessageBox.Show(carListBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
       string saveData = carListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

    }
```

MessageBox can't show string value and I can't get value after user selected.

MessageBox show [1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l79W.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to somehow get the `Car` object before you can have access to it's properties.

Something like this:

```
private void ListBoxOnSelection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
 Car myCar=carListBox.SelectedItem as Car;
 if(myCar != null)
   MessageBox.Show(myCar.ShowDetail); //or any property.
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. You can accept the answer to show that it's helpful.